# Emacs - предложения минибуфера

Tags: lisp, emacs

Как сделать предложения завершить команду в минибуфере сверху вниз? (А не снизу вверх, как по дефолту)

Comment: Объясните подробнее, что имеется в виду. Например, я всегда завершаю `M-x` либо `Ret` (выполнить), либо `C-g` (Quit). Это "снизу вверх" или наоборот?

Comment: Это как раз таки снизу вверх, а мне нужно сверху вниз

Comment: Нет, не понимаю я вашей терминологии. На каких-то примерах и лучше с привлечением [C-h r](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html) поясните

Comment: К примеру, мне нужно завершить предложение, я нажимаю "tab", и мне Emacs выдаёт предложения завершения сверху вниз (т.е. над эхо-областью, а мне нужно под ней отобразить)

Comment: Ага, т.е. вы хотите перенести окно минибуфера куда-то вверх, а под ним сделать окно с буфером `*Completions*`? / Если честно, никогда не делал таких команд.

Comment: Да, именно это я и хотел бы получить

Comment: Думаю, для начала надо [сюда](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/index.html#Top), потом [сюда](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Windows.html#Windows) (возможно посетив [это](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Minibuffers.html#Minibuffers)), потом прочитав все это подумать и написав нужную функцию прибиндеть  ее к `Tab` в минибуфере -) / Надеюсь, кто-нибудь заинтересуется этим и сможет вам помочь...

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Ну, извините...

Comment: Дополню. Похоже я вас обманул и как вы хотите, сделать не получится, поскольку  "[Minibuffers are displayed only in special windows used only for minibuffers; these windows always appear at the bottom of a frame](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Intro-to-Minibuffers.html#Intro-to-Minibuffers)". Вот это замечание *`always appear at the bottom of a frame`* и не позволит выполнить набросанный мною выше план (- / А за интересный вопросик, спасибо!